# Is cutting and pasting an article plagiarism?

Tags: discussion

I have seen several answers lately that have been essentially a cut and paste of another article on the web. Are these plagiarism?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes.

[Plagiarism is not acceptable on any Stack Exchange site.](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) Examples of plagiarism include, but are not limited to:

- Copying any amount from a source without any attribution
- Copying your entire answer from a source, regardless of attribution
- Copying your entire answer from a source, even if you reword parts of it, regardless of attribution

Please refrain from committing plagiarism, and [raise a flag](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) when you see it.

At the bottom of every post -- question or answer -- is your name. It's *your* post. It should be *your* ideas. The best answers always cite their sources in support of the ideas of the author (you). Lifehacks exists to share ideas, and we want to hear your ideas! Your ideas are welcome to be about a hack you've invented or a hack you've found from another source (with attribution).

Comment: I tried several limit myself to the links to the solution but was slapped by moderators, as not qualifying answer or adviced to copy the full answer because internet pages are never permanent and can be deleted.

Comment: That happened however on a sister site (stackoverflow), perhaps live hacks demands are different from computer hacks and need different policy.

Comment: The link you provided only says that plagiatrism is frowned upon, rather than is not acceptable.

Comment: @Serge From the help center: "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own." This is saying "Do not..." very clearly.